# How to Normalize LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq, optimization

I have this linq query, which contains 7 tables to get users transactions,

```
var transLst = from trans in context.CommunicationTransactions
               join cc in context.CommunicationCases on trans.CommunicationCaseId equals cc.CommunicationCaseId
               join cw in context.CommunicationWays on trans.CommunicationWayId equals cw.CommunicationWayId
               join mem in context.Members on trans.MemeberId equals mem.MemberId
               join us in context.Users on trans.UserId equals us.UserId
               join loc in context.Locations on mem.MemberLocationId equals loc.LocationId
               join ar in context.Areas on loc.LocationAreaId equals ar.AreaId
               where
                       (AreasIdsList.Count.Equals(0) || AreasIdsList.Contains(ar.AreaId)) &&
                       trans.CommunicationDate == (from transSub in context.CommunicationTransactions
                                                   where transSub.MemeberId == trans.MemeberId && transSub.UserId == trans.UserId
                                                   group transSub by transSub.UserId into t
                                                   select new { CommunicationDate = t.Max(d => d.CommunicationDate) }).FirstOrDefault().CommunicationDate
                       select new
                                {
                                    cc.CommunicationCaseDescription,
                                    cw.CommunicationDescription,
                                    mem.MemberId,
                                    mem.MemberName,
                                    mem.MemberMobile,
                                    mem.MemberMobile1,
                                    mem.MemberMobile2,
                                    mem.MemberEmail,
                                    mem.MemberOwnerName,
                                    us.UserId,
                                    UserFullName = (us.FirstName + " " + us.SecondName + " " + us.ThirdName),
                                    trans.CommunicationDate,
                                    trans.AddedDate,
                                    loc.LocationName,
                                    ar.AreaName,
                                    trans.TransId,
                                    trans.Comment,
                                    trans.CommunicationsGroupId,
                                    trans.CommunicationCaseId,
                                    trans.CommunicationWayId
                                };
```

When I try to track it with SQL Profiler, I found it translated as

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[TransId] AS [TransId], 
[Project2].[CommunicationCaseDescription] AS [CommunicationCaseDescription], 
[Project2].[CommunicationDescription] AS [CommunicationDescription], 
[Project2].[MemberId] AS [MemberId], 
[Project2].[MemberName] AS [MemberName], 
[Project2].[MemberMobile] AS [MemberMobile], 
[Project2].[MemberMobile1] AS [MemberMobile1], 
[Project2].[MemberMobile2] AS [MemberMobile2], 
[Project2].[MemberEmail] AS [MemberEmail], 
[Project2].[MemberOwnerName] AS [MemberOwnerName], 
[Project2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
CASE WHEN ([Project2].[FirstName] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Project2].[FirstName] END + N'' '' + 
CASE WHEN ([Project2].[SecondName] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Project2].[SecondName] END + N'' '' + 
    CASE WHEN ([Project2].[ThirdName] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Project2].[ThirdName] END AS [C1], 
[Project2].[CommunicationDate] AS [CommunicationDate], 
[Project2].[AddedDate] AS [AddedDate], 
[Project2].[LocationName] AS [LocationName], 
[Project2].[AreaName] AS [AreaName], 
[Project2].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Project2].[CommunicationsGroupId] AS [CommunicationsGroupId], 
[Project2].[CommunicationCaseId] AS [CommunicationCaseId], 
[Project2].[CommunicationWayId] AS [CommunicationWayId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[TransId] AS [TransId], 
    [Extent1].[CommunicationCaseId] AS [CommunicationCaseId], 
    [Extent1].[CommunicationDate] AS [CommunicationDate], 
    [Extent1].[CommunicationWayId] AS [CommunicationWayId], 
    [Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Extent1].[AddedDate] AS [AddedDate], 
    [Extent1].[CommunicationsGroupId] AS [CommunicationsGroupId], 
    [Extent2].[CommunicationCaseDescription] AS [CommunicationCaseDescription], 
    [Extent3].[CommunicationDescription] AS [CommunicationDescription], 
    [Extent4].[MemberId] AS [MemberId], 
    [Extent4].[MemberName] AS [MemberName], 
    [Extent4].[MemberMobile] AS [MemberMobile], 
    [Extent4].[MemberEmail] AS [MemberEmail], 
    [Extent4].[MemberOwnerName] AS [MemberOwnerName], 
    [Extent4].[MemberMobile1] AS [MemberMobile1], 
    [Extent4].[MemberMobile2] AS [MemberMobile2], 
    [Extent5].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent5].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent5].[SecondName] AS [SecondName], 
    [Extent5].[ThirdName] AS [ThirdName], 
    [Extent6].[LocationName] AS [LocationName], 
    [Extent7].[AreaName] AS [AreaName], 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent8].[UserId] AS [K1], 
            MAX([Extent8].[CommunicationDate]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[CommunicationTransactions] AS [Extent8]
            WHERE ([Extent8].[MemeberId] = [Extent1].[MemeberId]) AND ([Extent8].[UserId] = [Extent1].[UserId])
            GROUP BY [Extent8].[UserId]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]) AS [C1]
    FROM       [dbo].[CommunicationTransactions] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CommunicationCases] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CommunicationCaseId] = [Extent2].[CommunicationCaseId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CommunicationWays] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CommunicationWayId] = [Extent3].[CommunicationWayId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Members] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[MemeberId] = [Extent4].[MemberId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent5].[UserId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Locations] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[MemberLocationId] = [Extent6].[LocationId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Areas] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[LocationAreaId] = [Extent7].[AreaId]
)  AS [Project2]
WHERE (0 = @p__linq__0) AND ([Project2].[CommunicationDate] = [Project2].[C1])',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

What I'm doing wrong in this statement to got it like this ? any help to edit my code for enhancement ? or this is the optimum output of Linq To Sql ?

Comment: What's wrong with the generated query?

Comment: It's huge as you see, and I'm using (Linqpad) to build and test my queries before work on it in my code, and the output of it for that linq query is as I'm expected, but when I tried to double check with profiler after use it in my code, I found a different output with many joins and sub queries not needed

Comment: That a Linq generated query turns out huge is not really something we can do much about. It's one of the dangers - and tradeoffs - of Linq and similar tools. If you want optimized queries, you're often better of writing it correct yourself.

Comment: Thanks @AllanS.Hansen